# Upload FormData in HTTPBody give Some HTML Error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an application which required to upload Profile image on server.

My problem is that below iOS code is working fine for testing server, but not in actual server.

iOS code is below.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData  alloc] init];
 //Image
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\" ; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imageObjName,fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:data];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data1, NSError *connectionError) {
            }];
```

HTML ERROR is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 webmaster@cloudchatt.com and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

please suggest.

Comment: Check server configuration. Server accepted content type and string format for the request, also check parameters in form data are acceptable on server.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I check server accepted content type?

Comment: When I try same url with POSTMAN (Google chrome web app), it works fine.

Comment: You can contact to server guy and check for documentation. Don't you have server details? Have you just set this request on your own, with out the knowledge of server configuration?

Comment: can you please tell me that why it is working into POSTMAN?

Comment: I don't know about POSTMAN and how it's working. What I know you should check server details before make a request.